# Grails custom validation scenarios

Tags: forms, validation, grails

I just started looking at grails, I used to work mainly with PHP before, so my question is what is the best way of adding custom validation scenarios to a form. So lets say we have all the constraints in the domain but under a certain controller action where a form is bound to the domain we want to add an extra custom validation of some sort (for argument sakes, lets say we have a date and only in this scenario it should be more than 2 weeks in the future). Whats the best approach of doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you requirement you can using a [Command Object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects) with constraints:

```
@grails.validation.Validateable
class CommandObject {
    Date date

    static constraints = {
        date(/*constraint here*/)

    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Concerning your second question, yes you can share constraints from your domain object to your command object using `importFrom [EntityName]`, see the example from the doc:

**Domain object:**

```
class User {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String passwordHash
    static constraints = {
        firstName blank: false, nullable: false
        lastName blank: false, nullable: false
        passwordHash blank: false, nullable: false
    }
}
```

**Command object:**

```
class UserCommand {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String password
    String confirmPassword   
    static constraints = {
        importFrom User
        password blank: false, nullable: false
        confirmPassword blank: false, nullable: false
    }
}
```

[Sharing Constraints](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I assume the course of action is we bind it to the command, validate that, we then bind it to the according domain, valdiate that as well and then persist to the db, or we can somehow extend the domain so that the command object constraints get added to it? The second looks like a cleaner approach but im not sure if its possible?

Comment: You're welcome, I've added some info on how to share constraints between entities and command objects.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the form validation using jquery before it reaches the controller. If you want, you can also do individual validation on the gsp itself (ei. checking that the input field is required, accepts only emails, accepts integer only etc.). You can even do this on the controller. But I think form validation using jquery is already enough :)

Comment: Client-side validation is a nice enhancement, but is not a replacement for validating user input on the server. What if JavaScript is disabled? You can't trust client-side validation since you have no control over its execution. Also, the question is specifically asking about how to accomplish this in Grails.